# Query to find out the admin who added a particular user in a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am one of the Admins of a FB Group having above 20 admins in total. I was thinking whether it is possible to find out the Admin who has added a particular user in the group.

So, I thought about using the Graph API to query the Admin name of this group, who have added a user with the id xxxxxxxx. I tried digging the documentation of the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) as well as [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group/), but wasn't successful to find a way. Tried searching in Google also.

Is it possible to find out who(among the Admins) added a particular user to a Group ? If so, any tips or suggestions to find it out would be very helpful.

Thank you :)

Comment: Don't think it's possible to get this info.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) Sometimes I saw a a post in the wall like "XXXX had added ____ to this group" or something like that. I seldom saw these kinds of posts, which is system generated notification I believe. Will it be accessible using the API ? The doc doesn't mention anything about it though!

Comment: Yes, you can only look for "Bob added Fred to the group" stories in the group's feed.